# Loader not working while the data is being processed

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, loader

I think is because it gets caught in the loop of the components and doesnt let the component render the loader, but i dont know how to fix it.

```
const Simulate = (props) => {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true); 

    const steps = props.nodes[0].data.fields.arrivals;
    const duracionPrueba = props.nodes[0].data.fields.duracionPrueba;
    let stepsTime = arrivalSteps(steps, duracionPrueba);

    let visitas = []

    let llegadas = {};
    let finalizadas = {};
    let tiempoRespuesta = {};
    let errores = {};
    let filtrados = {};
    let concurrencia = {};
    let cola = {};

    let [nodesPath, tree] = NodesPath(props.edges)

    let leaves = [];
    findLeaves(tree, leaves);
    weightNodes(tree, props.nodes, props.edges);
    let segundo = 1;
    
    useEffect(() => {
        
        steps.forEach((step, i) => {
            let timeStep = 1;
            while (timeStep <= stepsTime[i]) {
                console.log(segundo)

                runPath(nodesPath, props.nodes, step, llegadas, visitas, finalizadas, tree);

                checkFinish(visitas, leaves, errores, filtrados, concurrencia, cola, tiempoRespuesta, props.nodes);

                segundo = segundo + 1;
                timeStep = timeStep + 1;

            }
        });
        while (visitas.length > 0) {
            console.log(segundo);
            runPath(nodesPath, props.nodes, 0, llegadas, visitas, finalizadas, tree);

            checkFinish(visitas, leaves, errores, filtrados, concurrencia, cola, tiempoRespuesta, props.nodes);

            segundo++;

        }


        let simulateResults = {
            duracionPrueba: duracionPrueba,
            tiempoTotal: segundo,
            tiempoRespuesta: tiempoRespuesta,
            concurrencia: concurrencia,
            cola: cola,
            errores: errores,
            filtrados: filtrados,
            llegadas: llegadas,
            finalizadas: finalizadas,
        };
        props.handleSimulate(simulateResults);
        setIsLoading(false);

    })


    if (isLoading) {
        return(
            <Modal
                open={isLoading}
                aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
                aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
            >
                <Box sx={{style}} className='loader'>
                <CircularProgress style={{transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)'}} />
                </Box>
            </Modal>
        )
    }
    
    
}
```

I tried to put the processing data code on a useEffect hook but it didnt work.